# How to know which element I'm dragging

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop

I'm making a drag and drop application with vanilla Javascript.
So with only 1 draggable element, it works well but when I have more than one, they don't actually drag, only one of them does.
I need to differentiate these elements to know which one I'm currently moving, but I can't come up with any solution.
I did some research and tried using the "ondrag" attribute, but I can't make something out of this.
This is my code so far:

```js
const filled = document.querySelectorAll('.fill');
const empties = document.querySelectorAll('.empty');

//fill listeners
for (const fill of filled){
fill.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);
fill.addEventListener('dragend', dragEnd);
}

for(const empty of empties)
{
    empty.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver);
    empty.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter);
    empty.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeave);
    empty.addEventListener('drop', dragDrop);
}


var element_id = "";

//drag functions
function dragStart(){
    this.className += ' hold';
    setTimeout(() => this.className = 'invisible', 0);
}

function dragEnd(){
    this.className = 'fill';
}

function dragOver(e){
    e.preventDefault();
}

function dragEnter(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.className += ' hovered';
}

function dragLeave(){
    this.className = 'empty';
}

function dragDrop(){
    document.GetElementById(id).className = 'empty';
    this.append(element_id)
}
function _(id){
    element_id = id;
}
```

```css
body {
    background: darkcyan;
}

.fill {
    background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random/50x50');
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
    cursor: pointer; 
}
.holders{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 55px;
    width: 55px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 3px gold solid;
    background: pink;
    position: relative;
}

.empty{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 55px;
    width: 55px;
    margin: 5;
    border: 3px black solid;
    background: grey;
    position: relative;
    top: 80px;
    left: 50px;
}

.hold{
    border: solid lightgrey 4px;
}
.hovered{
    background: white;
    border-style: dashed;
}
.invisible{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <title>DragnDrop</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="holders">
        <div id="0" ondrag="_(id)" class="fill" draggable="true"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="holders">
        <div id="1" class="fill" draggable="true"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="holders">
        <div id="2" class="fill" draggable="true"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="holders">
        <div id="3" class="fill" draggable="true"></div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div value="0" class="empty"></div>
    <div value="0" class="empty"></div>

<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not very experienced with javascript so I'd appreciate any explanation.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this now

```js
const filled = document.querySelectorAll('.fill');
const empties = document.querySelectorAll('.empty');

//fill listeners
for (const fill of filled){
fill.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);
fill.addEventListener('dragend', dragEnd);
}

for(const empty of empties)
{
    empty.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver);
    empty.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter);
    empty.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeave);
    empty.addEventListener('drop', dragDrop);
}


var element_id = "";

//drag functions
function dragStart(){
    console.log(this.id);
    this.className += ' hold';
    setTimeout(() => this.className = 'invisible', 0);
}

function dragEnd(){
    this.className = 'fill';
}

function dragOver(e){
    e.preventDefault();
}

function dragEnter(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.className += ' hovered';
}

function dragLeave(){
    this.className = 'empty';
}

function dragDrop(){
    console.log(this.id);
    //document.getElementById(this.id).className = 'empty';
    //this.append(element_id)
}
```

```css
body {
    background: darkcyan;
}

.fill {
    background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random/50x50');
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
    cursor: pointer; 
}
.holders{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 55px;
    width: 55px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 3px gold solid;
    background: pink;
    position: relative;
}

.empty{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 55px;
    width: 55px;
    margin: 5;
    border: 3px black solid;
    background: grey;
    position: relative;
    top: 80px;
    left: 50px;
}

.hold{
    border: solid lightgrey 4px;
}
.hovered{
    background: white;
    border-style: dashed;
}
.invisible{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <title>DragnDrop</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="holders">
        <div id="0" class="fill" draggable="true"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="holders">
        <div id="1" class="fill" draggable="true"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="holders">
        <div id="2" class="fill" draggable="true"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="holders">
        <div id="3" class="fill" draggable="true"></div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div value="0" class="empty"></div>
    <div value="0" class="empty"></div>

<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, that actually gives me the id of the element I'm moving. Now, how should I use that to move them independently?

Comment: @gezuz what do you mean by  "move them independently" ?

Comment: @gezuz https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wbeKbw?editors=1111. So this is still raw, the rest you should think how to implement it. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand that how ***addEventListener*** works.

***`addEventListener`***: is a method available with DOM element which is used to attach event handlers with that DOM element. It takes two parameter first is event-name and second is handler-function/callback which gets call whenever that event takes place with respect to that DOM element.

***`Second Parameter / handler-function / callback`*** : This handler function's definition accepts one parameter as ***event***.

In your case for dragDop Event Handler you can specify `function dragDrop` as:

```
const empties = document.querySelectorAll('.empty');
for(const empty of empties)
{
   empty.addEventListener('drop', dragDrop);
}

function dragDrop(event){
   //your code
}
```

***`event`***: This parameter to handler function is an object which have target as an attribute which contains DOM element which emits this event as value. So inside your handler you can access element you are interested in as : ***`event.target`***

Comment: This does the job by overriding dragDrop.